# Extracting a substring following a specific pattern using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string:

```
lx-ss {\n    id 1;\n    type mx2090;\n    template 4-32g;\n}\nlaxmx2k02-ie {\n    id 2;\n    chss mx2010;\n    resource-plate 4co;\n}\ncable {\n    id 3;\n    chassis mx2010;\n    plate 2c;\n}\n
```

I need to extract `cable {\n    id 3;\n    chassis mx2010;\n    plate 2c;\n}\n` from the above string.

The regex that I am following is:

`[\n\r].*\ncable:\s*([^\n\r]*)`

But it's not working.

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should explain exactly what you mean by: "it's not working". In addition, specify what you're trying to extract. If you're just looking for that exact string then you can do a hard match for that string. If you can provide 2-3 examples (they don't need to be the full text string) then you'll find people can give much better answers.

Comment: That looks like some kind of serialized data structure, similar to JSON. Maybe regexes are not the best tool to decode it. Where does this string come from? What do you intend to do with the `cable { ... }` result?

Comment: One reason why your regex attempt doesn't work is that the pattern has `cable:` but the string has `cable` without `:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.search` and extract your string.

---

**Option 1**

```
.*\n(.*{.*}\n)
```

```
m = re.search('.*\n(.*{.*}\n)', string, re.DOTALL | re.M)

print(m.group(1))    
'cable {\n    id 3;\n    chassis mx2010;\n    plate 2c;\n}\n'
```

**Regex Details**

```
.*       # greedy match (we don't capture this)
\n       # newline
(        # first capture group - capture everything inside this
    .*       
    {        # opening brace
    .*       # content within braces (greedy/non-greedy doesn't matter)
    }        # closing brace
    \n       
)
```

---

**Option 2**
This one is a bit more flexible, with regards to the positioning of your substring.

```
(cable\s*{.*?}\n?)
```

```
m = re.search('(cable.*?{.*?}\n?)', string, re.DOTALL | re.M).group(1)
print(m.group(1))  
'cable {\n    id 3;\n    chassis mx2010;\n    plate 2c;\n}\n'
```

**Regex Details**

```
(            # first capture group
    cable        # match "cable"
    \s*          # match 0 or more whitespace char
    {            # opening brace 
    .*?          # non-greedy matchall
    }            # closing brace
    \n?          # optional newline
)
```

Comment: Good guess for what OP is looking for, but super hard to be certain.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Agreed... I was itching to flex my fingers :-)

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Added another possible regex solution.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You should probably replace `.*?` with `\s*` at the beginning like so: `cable\s*{.*?}\n?` That way it doesn't catch something like `cables {}`

Comment: @ctwheels It's a non-greedy capture group, so that won't happen.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it will happen because you have he opening brace directly following it. Try it on regex101 and you’ll see it catches `cables`. See it catch `cables` on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/5FBPle/1 now change it to the code I wrote above and see what happens

Comment: Thanks for the answer @COLDSPEED